# Hyperlink in table header is not rendering

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to put hyperlinks/actionlinks in my table headers, for sorting purposes, but for some reason they won't render.

Any idea why it's not rendering properly? In the code below, you see the first table header is an Actionlink. The header renders is empty. I inspected the element and it indeed appears empty.

code:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<FitnerWebRole.ViewModels.CenterVM>
@using FitnerWebRole.Models
@using IdealDatabase

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Centers";
}
@using (IdealDb db = new IdealDb(ApiConfig.AppName, ApiConfig.DbServer, ApiConfig.DbUser, ApiConfig.DbPassword))
{
    <div class="container adminContainer event">
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
        </p>
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), PagedList.Mvc.PagedListRenderOptions.Minimal)
        <table id="centerTable" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = "name", currentSort = "name" })
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Address)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().ChainId)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().CityId)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().LangId)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Lat)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Lon)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Chain.Get(db, item.ChainId).Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @City.Get(db, item.CityId).Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Language.Get(db, item.LangId).Code
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lat)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lon)
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableControls">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                        <button id="delete" name="Center" value="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that it renders like this: `<table id="centerTable" class="table"><thead><tr><th></th>` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The first table header is just empty. I also tried using a normal anchor tag, with the same result.

Comment: When i refresh my page i can actually see it for a split second, then it goes away

Comment: Do you have some script which updates the table?

Comment: You have included `@Html.PagedListPager(...)` twice?

Comment: Yes i have included two pagers, but they are different. It's purely for better user experience, i don't see how it's relevant for this question? :)

Comment: No i do not have any scripts on the site, yet :/

Comment: is there any CSS that hides it or something?